# Java Не получается отпарсить html страницу

Tags: java, jsoup

С этой  https://companies.dev.by/ страницы мне нужно забрать все эти http://prntscr.com/f1r1yt ссылки. Пробую сделать через jsoup, но не получается.

Вот мой код:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<AllLinks> allLinksList = new ArrayList<>();
        Document doc = null;
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://companies.dev.by/").get();

        Elements h1Elements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "odd");

        h1Elements.forEach(h1Element -> {
            Element aElement = h1Element.child(0);
            String url = aElement.attr("href");
            String title = aElement.text();
            allLinksList.add(new AllLinks(url,title));
        });

        allLinksList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

class AllLinks {
    private  String url;
    private  String name;

    public AllLinks(String url, String name) {
        this.url = url;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AllLinks{" +
                "url='" + url + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 1):

Лучше использовать метод `select`. Вот так:

```
Elements h1Elements = doc.select(".companies a");

h1Elements.forEach(element -> {
    String url = element.attr("href");
    String title = element.text();
    allLinksList.add(new AllLinks(url,title));
});
```